# How to add file names from all uploaded images to database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, image, codeigniter, upload

I made an upload script to upload multiple images. This is working great, but I want to add the filenames to the database.

My problem is that only the last image uploaded, is added to the database.
This is because I don't know how to pass an data array to the model from the controller.

My code to upload looks like this (controller):

```
public function aanbiedingenadd() //functie om ze toe te voegen aan de database
{       
    $files = $_FILES;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($files);
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {

        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
    }
    print_r($image_data);
    print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->aanbieding_model->addaanbieding($image_data);
    redirect("members/aanbiedingen");
}
```

`print_r($files)` shows me all the uploaded files with their size, width, height, etc.

`print_r($image_data);` only shows the last image uploaded.

My model looks like this:

```
        $insert_data = array(
            'fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']
        );
        print_r($insert_data);
        die;
        $input = $this->input->post('userfile');
        if(isset($input)){
            $this->db->insert('fotoaanbiedingen', $insert_data);
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
```

`print_r($insert_data);` shows me

```
Array
(
    [fotonaam] => 'nameoflastuploadedimage'
)
```

How can I add this in an Array and add them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this lines inside the `for loop`:

```
$this->aanbieding_model->addaanbieding($image_data);
```

Comment: Now it only shows the first uploaded image from the `print_r($image_data);`

Comment: Okay, this fixed the problem, but now I have to edit my model so it adds the images for the same aanbieding. It adds a new row for each image. I want the images to be for only 1 aanbieding.

Comment: Shouldn't "what's inside the table" be more important than whats inside this array?

But just to clarify: $image_data get overwritten with the uploaded_data() each time the for loop is called. So naturally you're only seeing the last image in this array. Maybe you should fresh up on basic array stuff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Move `$this->aanbieding_model->addaanbieding($image_data);` inside your for loop, that's basically it.

If you get a lot of image uploads, you maybe should use an array to gather all the image data and then use [insert_batch()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert_batch) in your model.

e.g. in your controller :

```
$images = array();
$files = $_FILES;
$cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{
  // your upload routine here
  $images[] = $this->upload->data();
}

$this->aanbieding_model->addaanbieding($images);
```

And in your model you'd use `$this->db->insert_batch('fotoaanbiedingen', $insert_data);` instead of just insert.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your example shows that the $this->aanbieding_model->addaanbieding($images); is outside the for loop.

Comment: Yes, the example is to illustrate the usage with 'insert_batch' in the model. The difference is that moving the model call (with an insert) inside the for loop will get you 1 query per uploaded file, while 'insert_batch' just creates 1 query for all uploaded files.

Comment: Ok, it works now but when I upload 3 images there are 3 rows created, I want 1 row created with 3 images. 'I forgot to mention that I use joined tables, so 1 aanbieding can have more images (should be)

Comment: then you might want to start another question, because this needs a lot of different background info to get it done right, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a finction like this :-

```
public function fileUpload(&$uploadFileData,$field)
{
    $config1['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config1['upload_path']     = ABSOLUTEPATH.'category/original/';
    $config1['optional']        = true;
    $config1['max_size']        = '0';
    $config1['max_width']       = '00';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config1);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field,true))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $r = $error;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $r = "sucess";
    }
    $uploadFileData[$field] = $this->upload->file_name;
    return $r;
}
```

And call it like :-

```
    $field = 'userfile';
    $uploadFileData = array();
    $uploadFileData[$field.'_err'] = '';
    $isUploaded = $this->fileUpload($uploadFileData,$field);
    if($isUploaded != "sucess")
     {
     echo "error";
    }
    else
    {
    $imagename = $uploadFileData[$field];
    }
```

Comment: Not change whole code you have to change only $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
$this->upload->do_upload();
$image_data = $this->upload->data();